# Jquery datepcker

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using this code to disable today if time is past 2 pm. It works but I sometimes disable dates along the way. And currently, if tomorrow is disabled it enables it and makes it available. I don't want that to be the case. It should skip the already disabled dates until it finds an enabled date.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ryonwhyte/2CZtV/3202/)

My code so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".wccpf-datepicker-delivery_date" ).datepicker({ 
    minDate: +0,
    beforeShow : function(){
        var dateTime = new Date();
        var hour = dateTime.getHours();
        if(hour  >= 14){
            $(this).datepicker( "option", "minDate", "+1" );
        }
    }
});
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: make a demo and show us happening there

Comment: Here is a link [link]<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/1510/embed/"></script>

Comment: I couldn't delete the above
Here is a fiddle. In the fiddle I make it go backward to the the past dates that were already disabled dates. It should not have workked since those dates were disbaled. 
[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ryonwhyte/2CZtV/3202/)